# solving elliptical equation

Tags: python, ellipse

I am new to Python. I have the following equation of an ellipse

```
b[0] + b[1]*X + b[2]*Y + b[3]*X*Y + b[4]*Y**2 - X**2 = 0
```

the b coefficient vector is known. I am trying to find the values of `X` and `Y` that solves this equation and then plot it.

I have tried

```
Z = np.array([solve([b[0] + b[1]*Y + b[2]*Y + b[3]*Y*X + b[4]*Y**2 - X**2], Y)
```

for `X` in `np.linspace(-1, 2, 10)])` but it gives me 3d array of type object which I can't deal with.

Any suggestions on who to obtain Y vector and corresponding `X` vector to simply do

```
plt.plot(X, Y)
```

and then get an ellipse?

Comment: Can you provide an example `b` vector?

Comment: array([-0.43289427,  0.55144696,  3.22294034,  0.14364618, -2.63562548])

Answer (score 0):

you need this function for fit an ellipse :

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.linalg import eig, inv

def fitEllipse(x,y):
    x = x[:,np.newaxis]
    y = y[:,np.newaxis]
    D =  np.hstack((x*x, x*y, y*y, x, y, np.ones_like(x)))
    S = np.dot(D.T,D)
    C = np.zeros([6,6])
    C[0,2] = C[2,0] = 2; C[1,1] = -1
    E, V =  eig(np.dot(inv(S), C))
    n = np.argmax(np.abs(E))
    a = V[:,n]
    return a
```

and use it:

```
arc = 0.8
R = np.arange(0,arc*np.pi, 0.01)
x = 1.5*np.cos(R) + 2 + 0.1*np.random.rand(len(R))
y = np.sin(R) + 1. + 0.1*np.random.rand(len(R))

This becomes

a = fitEllipse(x,y)
```

for more information and tutorial see this link : http://nicky.vanforeest.com/misc/fitEllipse/fitEllipse.html but as a hint i just describe some of functions :

**numpy.linalg.eig(a)** : Compute the eigenvalues and right eigenvectors of a square array.
**numpy.linalg.inv(a)**: Compute the (multiplicative) inverse of a matrix.

see **[sci-py Linear algebra](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.linalg.html#linear-algebra-numpy-linalg)** wiki too !

Comment: Thak you so much for your detailed answer. I have already done the fitting by least square and obtained the coefficients of the ellipse equation. I just need to plot it? I am trying to extract the values of x and y (mesh) that will satisfy the equation and then plot(x,y)

Comment: you're welcome , So for plot you can use `matplotlib.collections.EllipseCollection` or other tools in matplotlib.

Comment: im not familiar with this myself ... this is the link : http://matplotlib.org/api/collections_api.html?highlight=ellipse#matplotlib.collections.EllipseCollection